# How to Install App as System App

Tags: adb, system-apps, safe-mode

My S3 has a damaged motherboard (says Samsung Tech Center), **only** boots into safe mode.

If I am to keep using the device I have to make the apps into system apps, so they run in safe mode.

One way is to use titanium backup (or other root file app) to make the app system, but the phone came back from Samsung **wiped clean**. It is still rooted, have SuperSu app installed.

Does anyone know how I can make a Play_Store or Downloaded_APK app system?

Comment: I won't tag this question as S3 or root because these details are specific to my own case, and have no relation to the broader question.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

[**Carl Parker**](http://www.androidauthority.com/author/carl/) writes about it on [*Android Authority*](http://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/):
(partly reproduced here in case the original post goes down)

> **For Apps Installed on the Device**
>
> - Assuming you have installed the app on your device, go to the app’s
>     Google Play Store link and take note of the words after “?id=” and
>     ignore the rest.
> - Connect your device to the computer via USB
>     cable.
> - Open the command prompt on your computer and type the following
>     commands:

```
adb remount 
adb shell 
su 
cd /data/app/
```

> - Type the command `ls appfilename*` (where “appfilename” is the app’s ID on Google Play
>     Store; make sure you include the asterisk at the end).  This command
>     will display the app’s complete APK filename.
> - Enter the following command:

```
mv apk_full_filename_here /system/app/apk_full_filename_here 
exit 
exit 
adb reboot
```

> - The device will now reboot. Your app is now saved as a system
>     app.
>
> **For Apps Whose APKs Are on the PC Hard Drive**
>
> - Open a command prompt on your computer and navigate to where the APK
>     file is located.
> - Enable USB debugging on your device and connect your
>     device to the computer via USB cable.
> - Enter the following commands:

```
adb remount
adb push apk-filename-here /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/apk-filename-here
adb reboot
```

> Your phone will automatically reboot. Your app will now be saved as a system app.

Comment: Hi, but where is the configuration of the system app is saved ? Is it also saved in /system/ ?